xsl:apply-template on nodes filtered by external xml file
I don't know the words for what I want to achieve, so I will try to explain as best as I can.
Feel free to redirect me to existing questions.
Say I have an XML file containing a list of classes (called index.xml):
<root>
  <classes>
    <class>
      <id>ClassA</id>
    </class>
    <class>
      <id>ClassB</id>
    </class>
    <class>
      <id>ClassC</id>
    </class>
  </classes>
</root>

And I have in another XML file some property details:
<root>
  <properties>
    <property>
      <name>MyPropertyA</name>
      <type>ClassA</type>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>MyPropertyB</name>
      <type>ClassB</type>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>MyPropertyE</name>
      <type>ClassE</type>
    </property>
  </properties>
</root>

I would like to have a selector for apply-templates on the properties only if their type is contained in the classes node-set of the index.xml file.
I think I need to reference index.xml using the document() function and use the key() function to lookup in the classes, but I don't seem to succeed in putting those pieces together to achieve my goal...
I tried something like that but it does not work:
<xsl:variable name="ClassLookup" select="document('index.xml')/classes"/>
<xsl:apply-template match="property[key(ClassLookup, ./type)]">

Any help is appreciated.
EDIT: I'm using Saxon HE 10.9 (XSLT 2.0)

In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153).

@michael.hor257k I've edited my post, I'm using XSLT(2.0).

I believe Saxon 10.9 actually supports XSLT 3.0?

@michael.hor257k yes it supports XSLT 3 but I think the program I'm using to transform the files is using an XSLT 2 transformer. (in C# it uses XsltTransformer and not Xslt30Transformer)

Start by identifying the processor that your program is using (see the link in my 1st comment how). Your testing environment is irrelevant if you cannot use the same code in production.

Saxon HE 10.9 is an XSLT 3 processor, whether you use XsltTransformer or Xslt30Transformer, these two are just different classes where Xslt30Transformer was introduced to provide a broader API to allow for all XSLT 3 ways to run/initiate a transformation.

Alright, I've learned something new. My xsl files are using xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" though. But knowing I could use XSLT 3 if needed is great.

The version you declare in your stylesheet makes very little difference - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#backwards-2.0.

Without a key, you would use <xsl:apply-template match="property[type = document('index.xml')/classes/class/id]">.
Using a key with secondary documents is easy in XSLT 2 and later so first state which version you use to allow us to tell whether a key is easily usable.

Thanks, it seems to be what I need, but it throws me an error he could not resolve the index.xml uri. I'll get back here to accept this answer when this error is resolved so I could check the result.

I've fixed my error and I'm getting the expected result, thank you!

With a processor that supports XSLT 2.0 or higher, you can define a key as:
<xsl:key name="class-by-id" match="class" use="id" />

and then do (from the context of properties):
<xsl:apply-templates select="property[key('class-by-id', type, document('index.xml'))]"/>


Note that by default the document() function expects a URI relative to the base URI of the input XML.

I've accepted other answer but this answer works too. Thank you!

Regardless of which answer you accept, I recommend you always use a key to resolve cross-references.
